# Looking for a special PEP for IF Python statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to check 34 variables in an `if` statement (given my problem, I have no other choice).
Is there any [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/) that advises on how to write the `if` statement in this case ? To be more precise, this is how my code looks like:`if((var1==stuff1)and(var2==stuff2)and ...)`
I am asking this question for the readability of my code.

Comment: What does "checking 34 variables" mean? Taking their `and`? Their `or`? Some complicated boolean formula?

Comment: @larsmans : `if((var1==stuff1)and(var2==stuff2)and ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no PEP saying how code should look except for PEP8. In this case, you can make two tuples `variables` and `stuff` and compare them with

```
variables == stuff
```

Or, if you need to preserve laziness, make two iterables for the variables and the "stuff" and compare with

```
all(x == y for x, y in zip(variables, stuff))
```